# Migrate: é possivel alterar uma tabela para adicionar uma coluna e já passar algum valor pra ela (excluindo a opção nullable())?

Tags: php, laravel, migrations

por exemplo eu tenho a table estudante (nome, idade);

Aí eu crio uma migration para adicionar o gênero (M/F)

```
 Schema::table('estudantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('genero')->nullable();
    });
```

mas ao invés de usar o nullable(), eu queria saber se é possivel criar essa coluna com todos os valores como M (masculino), por exemplo.

É possível isso?

Comment: Tente `$table->char("genero", 1)->default("M");`

Comment: funcionou, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim podes adicionar um default:

```
Schema::table('estudantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('genero')->default('M');
});
```

Desta maneira se não disseres nada em contrário aquando a inserção de uma nova linha esta coluna vai ser populada com o valor `'M'`

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! =)

Comment: @YgorDutra de nada. Deves aceitar a resposta sendo assim, por baixo das setas à esquerda